# What's a Warform?

Tags: product-identification

I saw the below (From [Here](http://rater202.deviantart.com/art/Human-Spiritshape-463483624))and am trying to figure out what a "Warform" is. Where do I find the information?

[image: Image want to know about]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## It is from:

[image: Exalted 2nd Edition]

The artist mentions the source material inspiring that series of images in [the second image in the set](http://rater202.deviantart.com/art/About-to-Exalt-463481286).

You can find generalized information from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exalted#). Or you can find detailed information from the [Unofficial Exalted Wiki](http://exalted.xi.co.nz/wiki/Main_Page). Or you can visit [White Wolf Publishing](http://www.white-wolf.com/), since it is their book.